# Number of records with a certain frequency in a grouped data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the number of times a record has a frequency greater than 3 in my pandas column `'Subject'` - grouped by date.

Currently this code works but it is for the data-frame overall.

```
main_subj = df['Subject'].value_counts(
[df['Subject'].value_counts()>3] count_main_subj = main_subj.shape[0]
```

I would like to group the data by `'date'` - in order to see how many records have a frequency above 3 each day.

My data-frame looks like this:

```
Subject  Verb     Object     ID         Date
trump     got     jobs        820108    20170803
voters    begin   to          182912    20170803
steve     miss    colleague   980828    20170804
```

For example if on one day there were 10 records:
5 with the subject trump
3 with the subject clinton
2 with the subject obama

The result would be 2 - the number of subjects that occur more than 3 times.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

`(df.groupby(['Date', 'Subject']).size() >= 3).sum()`

Example:

```
In [227]: df
Out[227]:
  Subject   Verb     Object      ID      Date
0   trump    got       jobs  820108  20170803
1  voters  begin         to  182912  20170803
2   steve   miss  colleague  980828  20170804
3   trump    got       jobs  820108  20170803
4   trump    got       jobs  820108  20170803

In [228]: (df.groupby(['Date', 'Subject']).size() >= 3).sum()
Out[228]: 1
```

If you want to get count by date:

```
d = (df.groupby(['Date', 'Subject']).size() >= 3).reset_index()
d[d[0]].groupby('Date').size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column named date, you can groupby date

```
df.groupby('date').size()
```

or

```
df[['Subject', 'date']].groupby('date').size()
```

This will output with the count you require

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I only want to know the number of subjects where there are more than 3 results for it. Unfortunately this just shows me the overall size per day.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need

```
s=df.groupby(['Date','Object']).size()
len(s[s>3])
```